# Eloquent Model with nested model issue

Tags: eloquent, laravel-7

I have got a couple of tables looking like this:

1) article

- id
- name

2) article_options

- id
- article_id
- option_id

3) option

- id
- name

An article can have none, one or many options and I want to return in the RestAPI a JSON structure that looks like this:

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Article1",
  "options": [10]
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Article2",
  "options": [3, 10]
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Article3",
  "options": []
}]
```

whereby 3 and 10 would be the option ids.

I tried a few solutions but none worked. Here is what I currently have:

Article Model:

```
class Article extends Model
{
#    protected $with = ['Article_Option'];

    public function options()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Article_Option');
    }
}
```

Article Controller:

```
class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $articles = Article::all();

        return response()->json(
            $articles
        , 200);
    }
}
```

I just can't get my head around how the model and the controller should be configured to achieve this.

Please help.

Thanks
Goppi

**[UPDATE]**

Thanks to Hides help. With some modification I got it to work the way I wanted. Here is all the code...

Article model:

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model
{
  public function options()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Option');
  }
}
```

ArticleController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Article;
use App\Http\Resources\Article as ArticleResource;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ArticleController extends Controller
{
  public function index()
  {
    $articles = ArticleResource::collection(Article::all());

    return response()->json ($articles, 200);
  }
}
```

and the Resource:

```
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class Article extends JsonResource
{
  public function toArray($request)
  {
    return [
    'id' => $this->id,
    'name' => $this->name,
    'options' => $this->options->pluck('id')->all()
    ];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`article_options` is your pivot table and the relationship between article and options is a many to many relationship which laravel provides a function for [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many). So all you will have to do is add the relationship to your `article` model.

```
public function options() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Option::class);
}
```

then when getting the articles you can call that relationship.

```
$articles = Article::with('options')->get();
```

This will grab all articles with all option relations and format it in the way that you desired. Laravel can automatically work out which fields it needs to use to form the relationship between the tables so don't worry about that though it does have an option to supply them in the `belongsToMany` function.

If you are only wanting the id you can pass specific columns to the `with` function as below.

```
$articles = Articles::with('options:id')->get()
```

To then return in a json format you can use [resources](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources). Resources help better format the collection of the model which can be used to achieve what you want. You will need to create a resource for articles. In the article resource you can format it how you wanted and to format the options you can use collection methods to transform it into an array of ids by plucking the field from the collection.

Article Resource

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
       'id' => $this->id,
       'name' => $this->name,
       'options' => $this->options->pluck('id')->all(),
    ];
}
```

So once you have got the articles you can return them like so

```
return new ArticlesResource::collection($articles);
```

If later on you can wanting to pass additional columns through for options you can create an options resource and pass that to the options key in you article resource.

```
'options' => new OptionsResource::collection($this->options)
```

Comment: I changed my code only with the first part so far (without the toArray), but I'm getting a "Class 'Option::class' not found". It's however defined as "class Option extends Model"...

Comment: Have you run `composer dump-autoload` in your terminal? Where are you using `Article_Option::class`?

Comment: Was a typo - I should have referenced the option class only. I corrected that already in my comment and got he first part to work as well by replacing the "Option::class" with "App\Option". Why does the ::class not work though?

Comment: The `Option::class` assumes that where ever you are calling it from is in the same namespace as the `Option` model. So your Article model is in `App\Article`

Comment: Yes, all models are in App

Comment: Not sure why then. They need have the same namespace and have been autoloaded. Still you have the relationship working now, has my answer helped you?

Comment: Interestingly, specifying :id in the with statement, results in just the id of the option model, but still also all fields from the pivot table. As such I initially configured a resource and later a collection - but i get in both cases the error "Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance". For troubleshooting purpose I now only include fields from article in the toArray - yet, it's still resulting in the same error !?

Comment: Ah it's because `$this` in `$this->id` is referencing a collection of articles not a single article. So instead of `new ArticleCollection(` you need it as a resource as above in my answer `ArticlesResource::collection(`. When you are setting the options in that array you are getting article_option, this variable is referencing the collection that you use for the 'with' function. So right now you have `with('options')` so it'll be `$this->options` not `$this->article_option`

Comment: The `belongsToMany` relationship is linking your tables article and options by using a pivot table called article_options and returning the options table, not the article_options table

Comment: I had it like ArticlesResource::collection(, but it causes this error: "syntax error, unexpected 'collection' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$'"

Comment: How can I close this article and make you the solution provider though with the modifications I stated in my update?